# Why this code works well in MySQL but not in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a question in Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-duplicate-emails/solution/

Basically the question asks to delete duplicate emails and keep the one that has the minumal index.

My code is the following one, and I firstly ran it in **SQL Server** mode, and it shows "Internal Error". But it has passed in **MySQL** mode. Why does this happen? Are there any syntax differences between them shown in this case? Thanks.

```
delete from Person
where Id not in (
select temp.minimum from 
(select min(Id) as minimum from Person group by Email) as temp
);
```

Comment: Yeah. SQL is not SQL - it is likely the most NOT standardized langauge ever created. In practice every product has a very different dialect.

Comment: I thought the MS SQL syntax looked OK.  It also checks up all OK in SSMS

Comment: . . . . What `Internal Error` you got ?

Comment: Probably just an issue on the leetcode side

Comment: I think above query works both on MySQL and SQL Server. If it was a T-SQL syntax error I believe the leetcode client would report it. Most likely there was an Internal Server error in Leetcode servers

Comment: Explain what you want to do. Even in MySQL 8, there are probably easier ways to write what you want than a triply-nested query. If you want to deduplicate rows by email,  you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a CTE both in SQL Server and MySQL

Comment: The error is simply "Internal Error" without additional information. Personally I agree with that it is because of Leetcode's side problem.

Comment: @60221611, did you run the internal SELECT to see that it's good to go?

Comment: @60221611 This triply-nested query is really bad - it forces a full table scan to calculate the GROUP BY and HAVING, then another seek (I hope) to find the rows to delete. The "accepted" solution in `leetcode` does a full self-join on `email`, which could be quite clean. In MySQL 8/SQL Server, the CTE and ROW_Number will find the non-duplicates in a single pass. You'll have to compare exeuction plans for both queries (accepted and ROW_NUMBER) to find which is best

Comment: @LongChalk Yes...and I have tried in SSMS and it works well. Maybe not SQL Server's problem :-)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Got it. And multiple select clauses always make me kind of confused...

Answer (score 1):

In `SQL Server` you use *CTE* with `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
WITH cte AS (
     SELECT P.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.email ORDER BY id) AS seq
     FROM Person P
)
DELETE
FROM cte c
WHERE c.seq > 1;
```

However, your original version of query should also work in `SQL Server`.

Comment: Does this work?  It is `DELETEing` from the pseuo-table created by `WITH` (`cte`).

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. Perhaps

```
DELETE FROM Person
WHERE Id not in ( Select Id FROM
      (SELECT Email,  
        MIN(Id) as Id, COUNT(*) as N 
        FROM Person 
        GROUP BY Email
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as temp
);
```

Make sure to run the inner SELECT by itself to see it's the same schema.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on sql server express 10.50.6560 and it seems it works...

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
  ID INT NOT NULL
, EMAIL VARCHAR(1000)
)

ALTER TABLE PERSON
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PERSON
PRIMARY KEY (ID)


INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES(1, 'AAAAA')
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES(2, 'AAAAA')
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES(3, 'BBBBB')

DROP TABLE PERSON
```

--Your query

```
delete from Person
where Id not in (
select temp.minimum from 
(select min(Id) as minimum from Person group by Email) as temp
);
```

It deletes one row...

Hope it helps